# Find equation of cubic from turning points

Tags: calculus, cubics

If I have a cubic where I know the turning points, can I find what its equation is?

I already know that the derivative is 0 at the turning points. Other than that, I'm not too sure how I can continue.

Suppose I have the turning points (-2,5) and (4,0). I have started doing the following:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \text{ at turning points}\\
\text{So, } 0 = (x+2)(x-4)\\
$$
$$
\int (x+2)(x-4) dx\\
= \int x^2-2x-8 dx\\
= \frac{x^3}{3} - x^2 - 8x + C
$$

Graphing this, you get correct $x$ coordinates at the turning points, but not correct $y$.

I'm aware that only with that information you can't tell how steep the cubic will be, but you should at least be able to find some sort of equation.

Finally, would a $y$-intercept be helpful? If so, then suppose for the above example that the $y$-intercept is 4.

Comment: if $y=4$ when $x=0$ then $C=4$ and you almost have your equation. You need one more point as @Bernard noted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome! You simply forgot that having the turning points provides the derivative up to a nonzero constant factor, i.e.
$$y'(x)=K(x+2)(x-4),\quad K\in \mathbf R^*, \quad
\text{ whence }\;y(x)=K\biggl(\frac{x^3}3 -x^2-8x\biggr)+C.$$
You now have two constants to adjust the ordinates.

Comment: Forgive my slow understanding, but how can I determine K in my example?

Comment: Writing $y(-2)=5$ and $y(4)=0$ results in two linear equations in $K$ and $C$

Comment: See my answer for all the details.

Answer (score 0):

If the turning points
of a cubic polynomial
$f(x)$ are
$(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$
then
$f(x)
=k(\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{(a+c)x^2}{2}+acx)+h
$
where
$k
=-\dfrac{6(b-d)}{(a-c)^3}
$
and
$h
=\dfrac{b+d}{2}-\dfrac{(b-d)(a+c)(a^2+c^2-4ac)}{2(a-c)^3}
$.

Here's the details.

If the turning points are
$(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$
then
$f'(x)
=k(x-a)(x-c)
=k(x^2-(a+c)x+ac)
$.

Then
$f(x)
=k(\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{(a+c)x^2}{2}+acx)+h
$.

$f(a)
=k(\dfrac{a^3}{3}-\dfrac{(a+c)a^2}{2}+a^2c)+h
=b
$
and
$f(c)
=k(\dfrac{c^3}{3}-\dfrac{(a+c)c^2}{2}+ac^2)+h
=d
$.

Subtracting,

$\begin{array}\\
b-d
&=k(\dfrac{a^3-c^3}{3}-\dfrac{(a+c)(a^2-c^2)}{2}+ac(a-c))\\
&=k(a-c)(\dfrac{a^2+ac+c^2}{3}-\dfrac{(a+c)(a+c)}{2}+ac)\\
&=k(a-c)(\dfrac{a^2+ac+c^2}{3}-\dfrac{(a+c)(a+c)}{2}+ac)\\
&=k(a-c)(\dfrac{a^2+ac+c^2}{3}-\dfrac{a^2+2ac+c^2}{2}+ac)\\
&=k(a-c)(\dfrac{2(a^2+ac+c^2)-3(a^2+2ac+c^2)+6ac}{6})\\
&=k(a-c)(\dfrac{-a^2-c^2+2ac}{6})\\
&=-k(a-c)(\dfrac{(a-c)^2}{6})\\
&=-k\dfrac{(a-c)^3}{6}\\
&=k\dfrac{(c-a)^3}{6}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$k
=-\dfrac{6(b-d)}{(a-c)^3}
$.

To maintain symmetry,
I'll add the two equations.

$\begin{array}\\
b+d
&=k(\dfrac{a^3+c^3}{3}-\dfrac{(a+c)(a^2+c^2)}{2}+ac(a+c))+2h\\
&=k\dfrac{2(a^3+c^3)-3(a+c)(a^2+c^2)+6ac(a+c)}{6}+2h\\
&=k\dfrac{2(a^3+c^3)-3(a^3+ac^2+a^2c+c^3)+6a^2c+6ac^2}{6}+2h\\
&=k\dfrac{-a^3-c^3+3a^2c+3ac^2}{6}+2h\\
&=k\dfrac{-(a^3+c^3)+3ac(a+c)}{6}+2h\\
&=k\dfrac{-(a+c)(a^2-ac+c^2)+3ac(a+c)}{6}+2h\\
&=k\dfrac{-(a+c)(a^2+c^2-4ac)}{6}+2h\\
&=-\dfrac{6(b-d)}{(a-c)^3}\dfrac{-(a+c)(a^2+c^2-4ac)}{6}+2h\\
&=\dfrac{(b-d)(a+c)(a^2+c^2-4ac)}{(a-c)^3}+2h\\
\end{array}
$

so
$2h
=(b+d)-\dfrac{(b-d)(a+c)(a^2+c^2-4ac)}{(a-c)^3}
$
and
$k
=-\dfrac{6(b-d)}{(a-c)^3}
$.

Answer (score 0):

If given points $(x1,y1)$ and $(x2,y2)$,

we can use the fact that the roots of the derivative are $x1$ and $y1$(simplifying everything else for now)

$f'(x)=(x-x1)(x-x2)$

and multiply out:

$f'(x)=x^2-(x2+x1)x+x2x1$

take the integral

$f(x)=∫f'(x)=x^3/3-(x2+x1)x^2/2+x2x1x+k$

simplify to a case where $x1$ and $y1 = 0$

$f(x)=x^3/3-x2x^2/2$

multiply function by a correction factor

$a=y2/f(x2)$

$g(x)=a*f(x)$

to add other values for $x1$ and $y1$, $x2$ to $x2-x1$, $y2$ to $y2-y1$

$h(x)=x^3/3-(x2-x1)x^2/2$

$b=(y2-y1)/h(x2-x1)$

change $x$ to $x-x1$, add $y1$ value to fit the curve:

$i(x)=b*h(x)+y1$

simplify

find $b$

$h(x2-x1)=(x2-x1)^3/3-(x2-x1)(x2-x1)^2/2$

$h(x2-x1)=(x2-x1)^3/3-(x2-x1)^3/2$

$h(x2-x1)=2(x2-x1)^3/6-3(x2-x1)^3/6$

$h(x2-x1)=-(x2-x1)^3/6$

$b=(y2-y1)/(-(x2-x1)^3/6)$

$b=-6(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)^3$

multiply $h(x-x1)$ by $b$

$i(x)=(-6(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)^3)((x-x1)^3/3)-(-6(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)^3)((x2-x1)x^2/2)$

Simplify

$i(x)=-2(y2-y1)(x-x1)^3/(x2-x1)^3+3(y2-y1)(x-x1)^2/(x2-x1)^2$

Add $y1$

$i(x)=-2(y2-y1)(x-x1)^3/(x2-x1)^3+3(y2-y1)(x-x1)^2/(x2-x1)^2+y1$

it isn't possible to do this with a quartic as there are 5 coefficients to solve for(in standard form) and getting equations with $(x1,y1)$, $(x2,y2)$, $(x3,y3)$ with each point satisfying the equation and each x-value being a root of the derivative, there are 6 distinct equations in a,b,c,d,and e, meaning there is not solution unless there is a special case.